# openXML save document convert to byte array send it has a .doc and new lines are lost

Tags: c#, openxml, doc

I am creating a very simple `WordprocessingDocument` using OpenXML like so:

```
public byte[] SaveCoveringLetter(string path, string coveringLetter)
{    
      byte[] result;
      using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
      {
           document.AddMainDocumentPart();
           document.MainDocumentPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document(new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(coveringLetter)))));
           document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
           document.Close();
           result = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
       }    
       System.IO.File.Delete(path);
       return result;
}
```

I then use this byte array to send over in a packet, but when it gets to the other side it is in the format of a doc but newlines are missing??? How do I keep the newlines?

Comment: Perhaps they're not missing, but maybe the other side is a different OS that uses different newlines. What is the OS on each side?

Comment: This probably wont help but remove document.Close() and move result = ... outside the using statement. (the using will do the close for you)